# osx modal is displayed on top of the parent window?

Tags: jquery, macos, modal-dialog

Can you pls help in displaying the osx modal window under a control in the parent window. rather than displaying it on top of the parent window.

Comment: what do you mean by "modal" window? using alert()?

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the way web browsers work. I suggest you to use a jQuery plugin that emulates a modal window.